# remove the black underline on hover for an image link

Tags: image, css, hyperlink

I'm havins some difficulty with my image links in google chrome.
the images get a black underline when they have been hovered over, how do i remove this I've tried

```
a {
   color: #000;
   &:visited {
      color: #666;
   }
   &:hover {
      outline-style:none;
      box-shadow:none;
      border-color:transparent;
   }
}
```

and

```
a {
   color: #000;
   &:visited {
      color: #666;
   }
   &:hover {
      border-style:none;
   }
}
```

along with loads of other things but nothing seems to work, the css does effect it but not how I want it to, Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: While it has been hovered over, or it remains after it has been hovered over?

Comment: When you tag a question with css, image, css3, hyperlink, your code should be real CSS. Constructs like `&:visited` are not CSS.

Comment: What do your image links look like?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I disagree with you there. A lot of coders write their CSS in SASS... I don't see the issue here.

Comment: @Mohamad, the code still isn’t CSS, and the question is tagged with css and css3, not sass. Since SASS is probably irrelevant here, it’s the resulting CSS code that should be posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underline comes from the `text-decoration` declaration, not the `border-style` one. You want to set that correctly:

```
a {
  color: #000;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

It's counter intuitive because your link happens to be an image, but the declaration targets the anchor tag that wraps around your image.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found that in rails when generating a scaffold a assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css.sass is created. this was actually the root of my problem. some default css is created in here that added the black underline in chrome, by removing this  I was able to remove the black underline on my image links on hover.
this default css could conflict with other styles you write so its an idea to check if there are styling conflicts with this also.